# Shift the index of sparse matrix without loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, indexing, sparse-matrix, shift

I really afraid to ask about this, but I don't know any way to shift the index of an sparse matrix without loop

Sparse matrix is something like this

```
a = 
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0

my initial matrix of indexes and value is:
a = [3 7 1;
     3 4 1;
     5 6 1; 
     5 7 1; 
     5 4 1 ]

uniq_x = [3,5]

uniq_y=[4,6,7]
```

desired output will be:

```
    out = [1 3;
           1 1; 
           2 2;
           2 3;
           2 1]
```

My initial solution looks like this:

```
for i=1:size(uniq_x ,1)
   a(a(:,1)==uniq_x(i,1),1)=i;
end

for i=1:size(uniq_y ,1)
   a(a(:,2)==uniq_y(i,1),2)=i;
end
```

any suggestion? thanks

Comment: I suggest you explain how you got to `out`. Also where are the `sparse` matrices?

Comment: but also you might want to have a look at the *third* output of the [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function. You'll still need to loop over the columns though (or if you just want 2 columns, call `unique` twice)

Comment: thanks @Dan for your helpful comment
I tried to improve question showing sparse matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, to get the desired result you basically need to remove columns and rows that contain all zeros, and then apply `find`:

```
[jj ii] = find(a(any(a,2), any(a,1)).');
out = [ii jj];
```

Answer (score 0):

As this question is uneccessarily unanswered, ill wrap up Dans' comment in an answer. Supposing the assumption upon the generation of the `out`vector is indeed the index of the i-th unique element per row, one can obtain the desired result by

```
a = [3 7 1;
     3 4 1;
     5 6 1; 
     5 7 1; 
     5 4 1];

% desired output
out = [1 3;
       1 1; 
       2 2;
       2 3;
       2 1];

% suggested method to create out
[~,~,n_x] = unique(a(:,1)); % [1,1,2,2,2]'
[~,~,n_y] = unique(a(:,2)); % [3,1,2,3,1]'
out2 = [n_x, n_y]; % result

% check for desired == result
all(all(out==out2)) % true
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dan and @Nras

Actually representing sparse matrix in Full mode shows me this is just like cutting zero rows and columns from left and top accordingly.

the answer very simply might be:

```
a = a(:,any(a,1));
a = a(any(a,2),:);
```

But the remaining concern is : there is no way to preserve original indexes for future use(e.g. if shifted index is ID of a user)

Comment: Yes, remove rows and columns that contain only zeros, _as I already said in my answer_